# Custom site template for publishing portal site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-site, site-template

I have created a custom site template with team site. 
When I deployed to a team or other than publishing portal site collection it shows the custom site template in defined category. But when I deployed to publishing portal site collection the defined category is not there..
Is there any specific reason? Or I'm doing mistake??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

publishing sites in SharePoint has much more than just the publishing feature. It includes special webparts to the masterpage and a unique hierarchy of form pages. So, Custom Team Site template will not work with publishing site.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43b97467-ae4c-4ec2-8b03-2c1d12bccbef/creating-a-custom-team-site-template-for-publishing-site-collection?forum=sharepointdevelopment

[Custom Publishing Site definition is unavailable to create sub sites under publishing portal site collection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2009/05/28/custom-publishing-site-definition-is-unavailable-to-create-sub-sites-under-publishing-portal-site-collection.aspx)